# how to use interface when a class that implements it have its own attributes?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, interface

I am using an interface reference variable to access the properties on an Interface

But in addition to that the class that implements the interface has its own attributes.

I am unable to access the class attributes through this interface reference.

Here are my questions:

1) why is that so?

2) What is the solution to the problem? Is there any way i can access the coolant power variable in AC class through machine only? Will a TYPE CAST work?

```
 interface IMachines
{
    #region properties
    int machineID { get; set; }
    static int totalID { get; set; }
    string name { get; set; }
    string make { get; set; }
    int weight { get; set; }
    int cost { get; set; }
    int warranty { get; set; }
    DateTime creationDate { get; set; }
    #endregion

    int generateWarrantyExpiry();
    int searchMachine();
}

public class AC:IMachines
{
    #region ACMembers

    protected int _machineID;
    protected string _name;
    protected int _weight;
    protected string _make;
    protected DateTime _creationDate;
    protected int _warranty;
    protected int _cost;
    public int _coolentPower;

    public int CoolentPower
    {
        get { return _coolentPower; }
        set { _coolentPower = value; }
    }

    #endregion




    #region IMachines Members

    public int machineID
    {
        get { return _machineID; }
        set { _machineID = value; }
    }

    public string name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set { _name = value; }
    }

    public string make
    {
        get { return _make; }
        set { _make = value; }
    }

    public int weight
    {
        get { return _weight; }
        set { _weight = value; }
    }

    public int cost
    {
        get { return _cost; }
        set { _cost = value; }
    }

    public int warranty
    {
        get { return _warranty; }
        set { _warranty = value; }
    }

    public DateTime creationDate
    {
        get { return _creationDate; }
        set { _creationDate = value; }
    }

    public int searchMachine()
    {
        //Search machine logic to be implemented
return 2
    }

    public void GenerateWarranty()
{
//generate warranty logic to be implemented

}

    #endregion
}
```

}

Comment: you can save yourself a lot of typing with autoproperties.  For example: public DateTime creationDate { get; set}

Comment: @dplante : i never type properties ... i simply use **Ctrl+R+E** shorcut ... it automatically implements property for an attribute itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that using a cast, as many answerers have suggested, will break the abstraction offered by the `IMachines` interface.

If it's true that you'll only ever be using the one type that implements the interface, `AC`, then this will work, but if you ever want to support some other type of `IMachines`, things may break down.

Comment: u think that AC , too should be an interface rather than a class?

Comment: @Sana.91 No, AC needs to be a class because it contains implementation - interfaces are abstract and can't contain any executable code.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use the "as" keyword to try a cast to the AC class:

```
IMachines machines = new AC();
(machines as AC).CoolentPower = 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

One of the fun things about using Interfaces this way is the ability to check if a generic variable implements the interface.  For example, you have a generic function that gets run at a lower level.  If the object you get given implements IMachines, do something special, or additional, to it.

```
public void DOSTUFF (object myobject)
{
    IMachines machine = myobject as IMachines;
    if (machine != null)
    {
        //do something special for IMachine objects
    }

    //the rest of the function that gets run against everything
}
```

and yes, to access the parts of the class that are not defined in the interface you have to cast to the type directly rather than using the interface.

Answer (score 1):

> Why is that?

An interface is a declaration of a *contract*. You are saying that the implementing type conforms to that contract.

When using the interface to access properties, you can only access those properties that the interface declared - how would the interface "know" about these properties? It would need to "know" about all the types that implement it and which one you mean exactly.

The solution is to use the interface when you need the interface abstractions and to use the concrete type when you need to use the type and all its defined properties.

Comment: so, practically ... programmers do not use cast to access properties that are defined in class and not in interface?? As in, they do not design the solution to problem as i have done above??

Comment: @Sana.91 - If one _must_, then casting is the solution, but as you say needing to cast is a code smell indicative of the wrong design.

Comment: @Sana.91 - Not always, but it is difficult to come up with a good scenario that requires it (at least _within_ the system).

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution, which calls `CAST`.

So cast to the type of the class implements it to access the properties/methods that not present in the inetrface itself.

```
var machine = (AC)interfaceVar;
machine.CoolentPower
```

Or, simply use [dynamic](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264741.aspx)

```
dynamic machine = interfaceVar; //no cast needed ! non need to "know" actual type
machine.CoolentPower
```

Comment: @Sana.91: the first example is a CAST, the second is a use of DYNAMIC

Answer (score 0):

you can access the attributes of your class if you cast it.

```
var cool = machine as AC;
```

Answer (score 0):

In answer to 1 - because an interface defines a contract that a class will implement, as such you can change the implementation as long as the contract (ie. the interface) stays the same.  What you are trying to do is get to properties that are not part of the contract - what would you expect to happen if you could access the properties of your AC class, but someone passed in an instance of MachineX that implements IMachine but doesn't have the properties of your AC class? The compiler cannot guess what to do in such an instance, hence you have to explicitly tell it that if your machine is an AC, then do something with it as an AC (and that's what the  other answers about casting it do).